# NSMutableArray Initialization at multiple indexes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Trying to create an array to store data about a deck of cards.
I'm wanting to keep a boolean for each card.

I want to create an array of capacity 52 with each index initialized to NO (or 0). Is there a way to do this all in one go instead of

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 0, 0, 0, .... nil];
```

Comment: You can't do it that way any way. You need `@NO`, not `0`, for each `NO` that you want. What you have will give you an array with no objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put all 52 instances of `@NO` as parameters to `initWithObject:` or create it as an `NSMutableArray` and use a loop to add 52 objects.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:52];
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    [array addObject:@NO];
}
```

BTW - passing a set of `0` to `initWithObjects:` won't work at all. Either use `@NO` for the `BOOL` value of `NO` or use `@0` for the number `0` (wrapped as an `NSNumber`). Just using `0` is the same as `nil` so no objects will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Use a  loop

```
NSMutableArray *deck = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    [deck addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
}
```